# give a subobject a pointer to a parent object in the parent object's constructor?

Tags: c++, oop, object, this

I am trying to find an easy way to assign the value of the "this" pointer to another pointer. The reason I want to be able to do this is so that I can have an automatic pointer to every seed's parent apple object. I know I can manually assign the address of a parent apple to a seed as such: MyApple.ItsSeed->ParentApple = &MyApple;      but I am trying to find a way to do this more conveniently using the "this" pointer. Let me know if this is recommended/possible and if so - tell me what I am doing wrong.

This is what I have right now:

main.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Apple.h"
#include "Seed.h"

int main()
{
///////Apple Objects Begin///////
    Apple       MyApple;
    Seed        MySeed;

    MyApple.ItsSeed = &MySeed;

    MyApple.Name = "Bob";

    MyApple.ItsSeed->ParentApple = &MyApple;

    std::cout << "The name of the apple is " << MyApple.Name <<".\n";
    std::cout << "The name of the apple's seed's parent apple is " << MyApple.ItsSeed->ParentApple->Name <<".\n";

    std::cout << "The address of the apple is " << &MyApple <<".\n";

    std::cout << "The address of the apple is " << MyApple.ItsSeed->ParentApple <<".\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Apple.h:

```
#ifndef APPLE_H
#define APPLE_H

#include <string>

#include "Seed.h"


class Apple {
public:
    Apple();
    std::string Name;
    int Weight;
    Seed* ItsSeed;
};

#endif // APPLE_H
```

Apple.cpp:

```
#include "Apple.h"
#include "Seed.h"

Apple::Apple()
{
    ItsSeed->ParentApple = this;
}
```

Seed.h:

```
#ifndef SEED_H
#define SEED_H

#include <string>

class Apple;

class Seed {
public:
    Seed();
    std::string Name;
    int Weight;
    Apple* ParentApple;
};

#endif // SEED_H
```

Seed.cpp:

```
#include "Seed.h"

Seed::Seed()
{

}
```

Everything compiles fine. But whenever I uncomment ItsSeed->ParentApple = this;         the program crashes without producing any output. This is a contrived example to demonstrate the problem. I feel like the problem is related to a misuse of the "this" pointer or it might have something to do with a circular loop of some kind. But I am not sure - I am not getting good results assigning the value of "this" to anything. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. You seem to be searching for a place to write `this` without any concrete need to do so.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit  There is a practical purpose for what I wanted to do - but I agree it was probably poorly explained and marred by a simple mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected, because you have not initialized `ItsSeed` to anything at that point; you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.  This triggers undefined behavior, which in this particular instance has caused a crash.

You need to initialize the pointer to something non-null before you try to dereference it.

For example, you might use a pair of constructors, and only set the seed's ParentApple field when you have been given a non-null pointer:

```
Apple::Apple() : ItsSeed(NULL)
{
}

Apple::Apple(Seed * seed) : ItsSeed(seed)
{
    if (seed) {
        seed->ParentApple = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it is the same, but it´d be better to use `ItsSeed` inside the constructor instead of `seed`

Comment: @K-ballo Maybe, maybe not. Stack-locals are more likely to be cached in registers, IIRC. In this case it may not matter, but in a more elaborate example the distinction between the two may be important. Of course that's micro-optimization, but if there really is no behavioral difference between the two then it's not really that important.

Answer (score 0):

Your program crashes because you don't have the `Apple::ItSeed` member initialized with a pointer to a valid instance of `Seed`.